# Is there a way to get a zestimate on my site, without going to Zillow everytime

Tags: java, php, mysql, api, zillow

Is there a way to get a zestimate on my site similar to the one on http://chattanoogapropertyliquidators.com/p/6656?
I don't want to have to go zillow every time and copy and paste the zestimate every time. I tried using the API calls tutorial on zillow but i feel like I'd be better off learning Greek. I have the address city and state already in my database and just want to display the zestimate value without searching everytime for it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample python code I wrote to scrape prices from an electrical parts website:

```
import re
import string
import urllib

#"http://store.platt.com/product.aspx?zpid=" + item_number
#<span class='ProductPriceOrderBox'>$0.349<

regex = re.compile("class='ProductPriceOrderBox'>(.*?)<")

def scrape_price(item_number):
    content = urllib.urlopen("http://store.platt.com/product.aspx?zpid={0}".format(item_number)).read()
    m = regex.search(content)
    if m:
        price = m.group(1)
    return string.strip(price)

print scrape_price(62408)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a web scraper written in python or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetZestimate](http://www.zillow.com/howto/api/GetZestimate.htm) API to get the Zestimate for a particular PropertyID.